# JQuery unable to find ID assigned to a newly appended HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `HTML` string, I've assigned the `div` with the class `parent` an `id` of `myid` (in the HTML string). I then append this `HTML` string to an element with id `main`. Using the browsers `inspect` tool I can see that the id has been infact assigned, but for some reason `JQuery` doesn't know about the newly assigned id.

```
var html = `
<div class="parent">
    <div id="content" >
    </div>
<div>`

var newHtml = $(html);
newHtml.find('.parent').attr('id','myid');
$('#main').append(newHtml);

console.log($('.parent').attr('id')); // Logged as undefined.
```

Comment: newHtml.find('.parent').each(function( index ) {
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});

Comment: @sudoman, you can use `find` in combination with `andSelf()` like in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`$.fn.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) targets the descendant elements where as [`$.fn.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) target the element at same level. As per your HTML `.parent` is at top level, hence you need to use [`$.fn.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) while setting the `ID` of `DIV` element.

```js
var html = `<div class="parent">
    <div id="content" >
    </div>
<div>`

var newHtml = $(html);
newHtml.filter('.parent').attr('id','myid');
$('#main').append(newHtml);

console.log($('.parent').attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

OR, You don't need to use [`$.fn.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) at all. Just directly use `.attr()`

```js
var html = `<div class="parent">
    <div id="content" >
    </div>
<div>`

var newHtml = $(html);
newHtml.attr('id','myid');
$('#main').append(newHtml);

console.log($('.parent').attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `find` method in combination with `andSelf()` method.

`andSelf()` method add the previous set of elements on the stack to the current set.

Read more [here](https://api.jquery.com/andself/).

```js
var html = `<div class="parent">
    <div id="content" >
    </div>
<div>`;

var newHtml = $(html);
newHtml.find('.parent').andSelf().attr('id','myid');
$('#main').append(newHtml);
console.log($('.parent').attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```